# Retrieve generic contract names for Managed Extensibility Framework

Tags: c#, .net, mef

**Edit**
Found the original contract name resolution by .NET MEF, the code below is not useful anymore. See response!

My issue was to use existing code, to make a MEF *`ExportFactory`*, imported via *`[Import]`* attribute to a property, return instances of Moq mocks (for unit testing). Problem was, that the original code always used the *`Type.FullName`* property value as contract name. This worked fine for non-generic types, but not for generics.

Generic `FullName` is like:

> ```
> My.Assembly.GenericType`1[My.Assembly.InnerType]
> ```

but MEF expects a name like:

> ```
> My.Assembly.GenericType(My.Assembly.InnerType)
> ```

The complete unit test code actually extends the MEF *`ExportProvider`* class, to register *`ExportDefinition`* instances for an *ExportFactory* and it's *`ProductDefinition`*. The contract name goes to a metadata dictionary, using the key *`CompositionConstants.ExportTypeIdentityMetadataName`*.

This following code is only for the contract name conversion. It calls itself recursively, for generic arguments which are generic themselves. The regular expression matches by the `[digits] name extension, used by .NET for generic types. It would be nice to see a generally better way, or already existing functions from MEF, if such exists.

Edit: I added the incrementor and code for open (unspecified) generics, which have names with indexed curly brackets: instead of *`IMyType<string,int>`* *`IMyType<,>`*, resolved to contract name *IMyType({0},{1})*. Regex has also been changed to match, if no type names come after `[digits].

```
private static readonly Regex GenericRegex = 
    new Regex(@"^(?<fullNameNonGeneric>\S+?)`\d+(\[.*\])*$", 
        RegexOptions.Compiled);


public static string ResolveGenericMefContractName(this Type type)
{
    return ResolveGenericMefContractName(type, new IndexIncrementor());
}

private static string ResolveGenericMefContractName(Type type, IndexIncrementor incrementor)
{
    var fullName = type?.FullName;
    if (fullName == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var match = GenericRegex.Match(fullName);
    if (!match.Success)
    {
        return type.FullName;
    }

    var fullNameNonGeneric = match.Groups["fullNameNonGeneric"].Value;
    var genericArgs = type.GetGenericArguments();

    return fullNameNonGeneric + "(" +
        string.Join(",", genericArgs.Select(
            ga => ResolveGenericMefContractName(ga, incrementor) 
            ?? "{" + incrementor.GetAndIncrementValue() + "}")) 
        + ")";
}

private class IndexIncrementor
{
    private int _value;

    public int GetAndIncrementValue() => _value++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the question was an attempt to generate type contract names, from the way I saw how MEF created them. Especially the difference from `Type.FullName`, which was previously used, when getting a contract name. For this reason, the code is a probably inferior re-implementation of MEF's own name generation, and should not be used for this purpose.

This is the contract name resolution used by MEF in .NET framework (maybe different namespace in Core, Apps etc.):

Namespace:

> ```
> System.ComponentModel.Composition
> ```

Static method:

> ```
> AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(Type)
> ```

Unfortunately, it's often easier to re-invent the wheel, than to find out about existing implementations...

Answer (score 0):

I see you've found the right solution but let's make a review anyway as there are few things that I'm not particularly fond of.

---

> ```
> var fullName = type?.FullName;
> if (fullName == null)
> {
>   return null;
> }
> ```

Instead of allowing `type` to be `null`, you should `throw` the `ArgumentNullException`. I cannot imagine any use-case where `type` being `null` would make sense. Usually this would mean a bug. You could return `null` later when resolving it fails but arguments should be always valid. Otherwise there are too many possibilities for the `null` result and it's could be difficult to tell why it didn't work.

---

The method name is confusing becaues it says *Resolve* while it actually creates a *MefContractName* thus at first I thougt that when the regex fails here

> ```
> if (!match.Success)
> {
>   return type.FullName;
> }
> ```

then it should return `null`. While in the first casae this would make sense, it wouldn't for creation so I suggest naming this extension as `ToMefContractName`. Now it all makes sense again.

I'm now sure what you need this `IndexIncrementor` for as the `type` should never be null so it will never be called.

> ```
> var genericArgs = type.GetGenericArguments();
>
> return fullNameNonGeneric + "(" +
>   string.Join(",", genericArgs.Select(
>       ga => ToMefContractName(ga, incrementor)
>       ?? "{" + incrementor.Next() + "}"))
>   + ")";
> ```

You can turn this into a more readable query without the helper variable `genericArgs` that this time doesn't help in any way.

This is how I think it should look like (with `IndexIncrementor` removed because I could figure out what it is for):

```
private static string ToMefContractName(Type type)
{
    if (type == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));

    var match = GenericRegex.Match(type.FullName);
    if (!match.Success)
    {
        return type.FullName;
    }

    var fullNameNonGeneric = match.Groups["fullNameNonGeneric"].Value;

    var genericArguments =
        from genericArgument in type.GetGenericArguments()
        select ToMefContractName(genericArgument);

    return $"{fullNameNonGeneric}({string.Join(",", genericArguments)})";
}
```

---

The `IndexIncrementor` should be called just `Index` and have one read-only property named `Value` and its method should be called `Next`. Saying `GetAndIncrementValue` reveals the internal implementation and this is not important to the user, he just wants to have the *next* value.

```
private class Index
{
    public int Value { get; private set; }

    public int Next() => Value++;
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks. But on `Type`, method `GetGenericArguments()` returns null for open generics; in this case, the code worked as desired. This is different from the `GenericTypeArguments` property, which returns only specified generic arguments. I just noticed this later, when trying again with the property.